# SVM and NN Model overfitting on large data

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network, text-classification

I have trained SVM and NN model using sklearn for two class. One class have 24000 tweets and another 32000 tweets.

When I do validation it gives like this

For -

```
text_clf = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')), ('tfidf',TfidfTransformer(use_idf=True)),('clf',MLPClassifier(activation="relu", solver='adam', alpha=0.001, hidden_layer_sizes=(5, 2), random_state=1)),])

              precision    recall  f1-score   support

    disaster       1.00      1.00      1.00     12862
 nondisaster       1.00      1.00      1.00      9543

   micro avg       1.00      1.00      1.00     22405
   macro avg       1.00      1.00      1.00     22405
weighted avg       1.00      1.00      1.00     22405
```

For

```
text_clf = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')), ('tfidf',TfidfTransformer(use_idf=True)),('clf',SGDClassifier(loss='hinge', penalty='l2', alpha=1e-3, random_state=42, verbose=1)),])
            text_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

              precision    recall  f1-score   support

    disaster       1.00      1.00      1.00      6360
 nondisaster       1.00      1.00      1.00      4842

   micro avg       1.00      1.00      1.00     11202
   macro avg       1.00      1.00      1.00     11202
weighted avg       1.00      1.00      1.00     11202
```

When I change `alpha` value in NN model from 0.001 to 0.00001

```
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

    disaster       1.00      0.99      0.99     12739
 nondisaster       0.98      1.00      0.99      9666

   micro avg       0.99      0.99      0.99     22405
   macro avg       0.99      0.99      0.99     22405
weighted avg       0.99      0.99      0.99     22405
```

When I test few records, it is always biased to one class. For example SVM was predicting every input to non-disaster and NN does it to disaster class.

Any idea or suggestion how can I fine tune this model?

Comment: @Yahya: What did you mean?

Comment: You aren't testing on your training data, are you?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have seen, this happens when the dataset is biased. I believe in the concept of Garbage in - Garbage out.

It would be good for you to visualize your train-test data. I believe it would be biased.

Having said that, assuming your use case to be disaster prediction from tweets, it is understandable that if you take a random set of tweets, not even 1 out of 1000 is going to be about a disaster.

Hence, it would be wise to scope down your query to a refined topic and users so that you get a good enough dataset.

Thoughts?

Thanks
Arun